# how to use profile in xcode4 with opencv?

Tags: macos, opencv, xcode4

i want to use profile in Xcode to analyze a opencv programs,

and "Architectures" and "valid Architectures"  is "x86_64"

but in got a message like:
"No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=ppc i386, VALID_ARCHS=x86_64)."

if i change "valid Architectures" to "x86_64 i386",the functions in opencv can't link

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to build your OpenCV with the x86_64 architecture included as one of the architectures that's compiled and linked into the OpenCV library.

Here's a potentially useful tutorial on how to do this:

http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/opencv-snow-leopard/

[And here is a related question that somebody else asked which also may help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781198/compiling-opencv-code-on-a-64-bit-mac).