# Why cant I compile this OpenCV 'hello world' using g++?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, linker, homebrew

I have installed OpenCV via homebrew, for my Mac OSX.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to use the `imread` openCV command at all. When I do, I get an error. Here is a breakdown of what I have done.

My simple code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat imageMe = imread("frog.jpg", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile, I type this into the command prompt:

```
  g++ opencvEntry.cpp -o opencvEntry `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` && ./opencvEntry
```

Upon doing that, the error message I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
          _main in ccvT5f6R.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So... I am not sure where/what is going on here. If I simply uncomment the `imread` line the file compiles just fine. However when uncommented, it does not recognize the command.

What is going on here?

Comment: `g++` is trying to link against an `x86_64` version of the OpenCV libraries, which apparently, you lack.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery Here's the thing though. If I use other functions of openCV besides 'imread', I get no problem. In fact, if I compile using cmake instead of g++, the code works. So I am trying to figure out how to get it to work via g++ ...

Comment: `cmake` is not a compiler and it probably uses `g++` under the hood. Can you take a look at the command line generated by `cmake`?

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery Gladly, but not sure how to do that... I basically followed this tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html).

Comment: Just run `make VERBOSE=1` and look for the commands that gets run

Comment: @nos Thanks nos, hmm, I did that but cannot seem to find any discrepancy... maybe openCV cant be compiled with g++ after all?

Comment: @Learnaholic it definitely can be. Maybe you are missing libjpg or cmake picked up the wrong version of it.

Comment: What is output of  "echo `pkg-config --libs opencv`" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, after searching, this is a solution which works for me, hope it can help you as well.

[Compiling OpenCV code on a 64-bit mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781198/compiling-opencv-code-on-a-64-bit-mac)

need LDFLAG of "-lopencv_imgproc".